# Javascript - Check Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have a toggle on button in my Application.

If the button ist toggled on, I want that the value is set to 1, and if not the value should be null.
(0=deactivated, 1=activated)

Thats my current javascript code:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("activate").value = '1';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("deactivate").value = '0';
    }
});
```

And thats my toggle button:

```
<div class="toggle">
    <label>
         <input id="CheckAcitavtion" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
         <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

But at the moment when I toggle the button the following error shows up:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
>           at HTMLInputElement.

Comment: There is no html element with the "activate" or "deactivate" id?

Comment: try doing with **id** instead of **querySelector**. Change it to `element = document.getElementById(id);` and set the `id` to the button one.

Comment: @ZombieChowder — The problem is with the code which uses `document.getElementById`. The only use of `document.querySelector` in the question is absolutely fine.

Comment: There's no element with the id that is being searched for. Voting to close this question as off-topic. It's basically a typo question. It's certainly not a useful question.

Comment: I'm sorry for that typo I didn't noticed it before I was posting this, it was from an old version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id's you pointed to didn't exist so i gave the span element this id. You should also use `innerHTML` instead of `value` for an element that isn't `<input>`.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("checkValue").innerHTML = '1';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("checkValue").innerHTML = '0';
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <label>
  <input id="CheckAcitavtion" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <span id="checkValue">0</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted! Thank you!